# how to display amount 123.45 as 12345

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do i remove the "." from decimal number and keep the 2 last numbers?

```
123.45 -> 12345
1.00 -> 100
```

Comment: I strongly recommend dealing with formatting in your front-end, not the database layer...

Comment: What should a value of `1.2` become? Just erase the "." and show "12" (see [answer by Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56686153/121309)) or treat is as "dollar value showing as cents" and show "120" (see [answer by Lukasz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56686136/121309))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REPLACE` function might do what you have in mind:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(123.45 AS varchar(max)), '.', '') AS output;

12345
```

### Demo

This answer is also robust with regard to numeric inputs which may not have any decimal component.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT CAST((col * 100) AS INT)
FROM tab
```